# Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa

Hello all I have following 2 tables that are related:

```
CREATE TABLE `documents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `documenttypes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `documenttype` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The models are as following.

The document type model

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "documenttypes")

public class Documenttypes {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "documenttype")
    private String documenttype;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDocumenttype() {
        return documenttype;
    }

    public void setDocumenttype(String documenttype) {
        this.documenttype = documenttype;
    }

}
```

And document model:

```
package com.example.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")

public class Documents {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

     @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        @CreatedDate
    private Date date_created;

     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false)
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        private Documenttypes typeid;
     @Column(name = "file")
     private String file;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Date getDate_created() {
        return date_created;
    }
    public void setDate_created(Date date_created) {
        this.date_created = date_created;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Documenttypes getTypeid() {
        return typeid;
    }
    public void setTypeid(Documenttypes typeid) {
        this.typeid = typeid;
    }
    public String getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }


}
```

Here is the repositories:
document type repo:

```
package com.example.repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.model.Departments;
import com.example.model.Documenttypes;
@Repository

public interface DocumenttypesRepository extends CrudRepository<Documenttypes, Integer> {

}
```

And my documents repository

```
package com.example.repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.model.Documents;
@Repository

public interface DocumentsRepository extends CrudRepository<Documents, Integer> {
    Page<Documents> findBytypeid(Integer typeid, Pageable pageable);
    Optional<Documents> findBytypeidAndDocumentId(Integer typeId, Integer id);


}
```

After all I am getting the following exceptions:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentsServiceImplementation': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentsRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentsRepository' defined in com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on EmployeersbootApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)! Reason: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.example.EmployeersbootApplication.main(EmployeersbootApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentsServiceImplementation': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentsRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentsRepository' defined in com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on EmployeersbootApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)! Reason: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentsRepository' defined in com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on EmployeersbootApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)! Reason: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)! Reason: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1061) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:360) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod.<init>(QueryMethod.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.<init>(JpaQueryMethod.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.DefaultJpaQueryMethodFactory.build(DefaultJpaQueryMethodFactory.java:44) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Please help. I don't even have a clue where I am actually scrooed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thrown exception already explained what happens :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid(java.lang.Integer,**org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties**$Pageable)

And the `Pageable` should come from the spring-data package which its fully qualified name is `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`

So you are simply importing the wrong package for `Pageable`