# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id" while trying to retrive related table column to jsp selectbox

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

This question kind of related to a previous one at
[Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.repository.DocumentsRepository.findBytypeid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69549816/could-not-create-query-for-public-abstract-org-springframework-data-domain-page/69550083#69550083)

Thank to all it was resolved. But now I have an other problem I am trying to make a selectbox with all rows from related column. Here is my JSP form

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Добавить отдел</title>
 <link href="../../webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="../../webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../../webjars/jquery/3.0.0/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <spring:url value="/document/add" var="addURL" />
  <h2>Добавить документ</h2>
  <form:form modelAttribute="documentForm" method="post" action="${addURL}" cssClass="form" >
   <form:hidden path="id"/>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Название</label>
    <form:input path="name" cssClass="form-control" id="firstname" />
   </div>
  
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Тип документа</label>
 <form:select path="typeid">
               
                <c:forEach var="documenttypeslist" items="${documenttypesList}">
                    <form:option value="${documenttypesList.id}" label="${documenttypesList.documenttype}"/>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
   </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Файл документа</label>
    <form:input path="file" cssClass="form-control" id="firstname" />
   </div>
  
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Сохранить</button>
  </form:form>
  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And part of my controller to add rows:

```
public ModelAndView addDocument()
     {
        ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView();
        Documents documents= new Documents();
         List<Documenttypes> documenttypesList=documenttypesService.getAllDocumenttypes();
            
        model.addObject("documentForm", documents);
        model.addObject("documenttypesList", documenttypesList);
        
        model.setViewName("documents_form");
        return model;
     }
```

And I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786) ~[na:na]
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:148) ~[tomcat-embed-el-9.0.53.jar:3.0.FR]
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-el-9.0.53.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:124) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:168) ~[tomcat-embed-el-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-el-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:692) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.documents_005fform_jsp._jspService(documents_005fform_jsp.java:223) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1400) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I am willing to provide more code if nessary, But it duplicates my previous question

I probably should add here my whole controller. May be it will be helpful.

```
package com.example.controller;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.example.model.Documenttypes;
import com.example.model.Documents;
import com.example.services.DocumenttypesService;
import com.example.services.DocumentsService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/document")
@SpringBootApplication

public class DocumentsController {
    @Autowired
    DocumentsService documentsService;
    
    @Autowired
    DocumenttypesService documenttypesService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView list()
     {
         ModelAndView model=new  ModelAndView("documents_list");
         List<Documents> documentsList=documentsService.getAllDocuments();
          model.addObject("documentsList", documentsList);
          return model;

     }
     
     @RequestMapping(value="/add/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        
     public ModelAndView addDocument()
     {
        ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView();
        Documents documents= new Documents();
         List<Documenttypes> documenttypesList=documenttypesService.getAllDocumenttypes();
            
        model.addObject("documentForm", documents);
        model.addObject("documenttypeslist", documenttypesList);
        
        model.setViewName("documents_form");
        return model;
     }
     
     @RequestMapping(value="/editdocument/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        
     public ModelAndView editDocument(@PathVariable int id)
     {
         ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
          Documents documents = documentsService.getDocumentById(id);
          model.addObject("documentForm", documents);
            model.setViewName("documents_form");
            return model;
     }
     
     @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView add(@ModelAttribute("documentsForm") Documents documents)
     {
        documentsService.addDocument(documents);
         return new ModelAndView("redirect:/document/list");
         
     }
     
     @RequestMapping(value="/deletedocument/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable("id") int id)
     {
         documentsService.deleteDocument(id);
         return new ModelAndView("redirect:/document/list");
         
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem can be a typo in your code In the definition of the `var` attribute. Please, can you try the following code?

```html
 <c:forEach var="documenttype" items="${documenttypesList}">
   <form:option value="${documenttype.id}" label="${documenttype.documenttype}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Please, note the change from `documenttypesList` to `documenttypeslist`.

In addition, probably you can simplify the `form:select` expression. Please, try:

```html
<form:select path="typeid">
  <form:options items="${documenttypesList}"
    itemLabel="documenttype" 
    itemValue="id" />
</form:select>
```

Or just:

```html
<form:select
  path="typeid"
  items="${documenttypesList}"
  itemLabel="documenttype" 
  itemValue="id">
</form:select>
```

Comment: I tryed. Now it was adding one empty option and then I tryed to change from what I have now in a controller to this model.addObject("documenttypeslist", documenttypesList); and after that got a same exception.

Comment: Hi @BogdanOnyshenko. Thank you for the feedback. No, please, there is no need to change the model variable name to `documenttypeslist` in the controller. The change should be only performed when using the tag library in the JSP. I changed my answer to clarify this point and to provide further alternatives. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for beeing with me here. The first form:select gives me org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/documents_form.jsp (line: [28], column: [2]) According to TLD, tag [form:options] must be empty, but is not
But second gives empty select .

Comment: I actually aded a whole controller. May be it will be any helpful...

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help. Of course mate, sorry, I copy and paste from the `form:select` provided example and didn't realize that. Please, see the updated answer. The strange thing is that it doesn't show any values. Sorry, perhaps I am missing something. If you debug the code in your controller, the variable `documenttypesList` contains the proper values?

Comment: Please, try debugging the mentioned variable like this:
`<c:forEach var="documenttype" items="${documenttypesList}">
   Id: <c:out  value="${documenttype.id}"/>
   Type: <c:out value="${documenttype.documenttype}"/>
</c:forEach>`

Comment: Thank you for your help! it was my bad at the your answer's point. I went to so called documenttypesController and simply copied values from there. And added the third example you provided and now it is working perfectly. Now I will try to provide a selected value to this list while editing the row. So posibly will be back :)

Comment: That is great, I am happy to hear that it worked properly!!